# International word-search: Can you find the words in multiple languages?

Tags: word-search

**This time it is not complicated. No tricks, no brain bending involved. A simple, straight forward word-search puzzle to relax...**

- All valid words are **straight lines** but can be found in any of the **8 directions**
- All valid words are **at least 6 letters long**
- All special letters are replaced by their closest simple representation ( **Ñ --> N** ; **Á --> A** etc.)

*...with a twist:*

- Words are written in **multiple, different, European languages**
- **Only words which can be found in *at least 3 European languages* are valid ( "word-triplet" )**
- **Words of a valid word-triplets may not overlap with more than a single letter.** 
  (This automatically rules out words which are identical in multiple
  languages unless you find 2 variants which are spelled differently. It also rules out words which are just different by pre- or suffix.)
- **It is possible that words of *different* triplets share more than one letter.**

small spoiler (not needed):

> Yes, English is also used in this puzzle.

big spoiler (not needed):

> Finding *pairs* of words does not guarantee there is a *triplet*. Red herrings have been included.

---

```
P Y B E G R A F E N I S X J R L P 
I S V A T B A O E V A N O R E A O 
Y A B O A R D G A M E N R E K M M 
Y N B D L P Z R V H K M N N Q R M 
P A O B L A G I A A S G N I C H I 
A B M S Y N T Y M A P A I V A T E 
S B R E T T S P I E L O L U F E R 
P O R M I T S K N S O E T R M R D 
O R H G R I A V E O S A Z A K N O 
O L H C M V P U G N J P K J A I B 
R E M Z H A E H A A O P O A I N O 
T T A C O N S C I E N C E H R G K 
S A N Z S K I S R L G N G D C E O 
J D Z I T I E X R P H S Y Y R R C 
H L A T A T R R A M I R G S A S K 
B O N F G S D G M U A B L E F P A 
I P O G E F X S O C G E W E T E N
```

---

**Winner is, who first discovered *at least 5 valid triplets* (5x3=15 words!).**

**Answers have to list the word-triplets and their according languages in brackets.**

Bonus points if you discover more than that. 
There should be at least 6 valid triplets, but maybe there are more?

**Bonus question:** How many different valid languages can you find? (A language is considered valid, if it is spoken somewhere in Europe and if you discover at least one word with at least two translations found as well.)
9 different languages were deliberately used, but one can possibly find more than that.

Comment: If a word in the puzzle is the same in *n* European languages, then does it count once, or does it count *n* times? E.g. 'cafe' exists in both English and French. If it appears once then is that 1 language or 2?

Comment: Very creative idea, so way to go on that!  It could be tough for us non-polyglots, though.

Comment: It counts as long as you find 2 "café" which do not share more than one letter. However, "café" never counts, as it is not an at-least-6-letter word (in all languages!)

Comment: @tjbtech: Google translate to the rescue! (I speak multiple languages, but not 9 ;c) )

Comment: Touché, Google.  Touché.  (Thought I had an excuse not to try. ;( )

Comment: "This time it is not complicated. No tricks, no brain bending involved. A simple, straight forward word-search puzzle to relax..." Are you **sure?**

Comment: @warspyking well, relaxing and simple for folk normally hanging around here ;/)

Comment: Is "boardgame" supposed to be a single word?

Comment: @victor: Actually yes.

Comment: I can't possibly solve this, but at least I learned some words in languages I knew nothing about so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the answer is lengthy, I start with a table of contents:

**Part 1: Explanation of my numbering system

Part 2: Numbering shown around the table of letters

Part 3: Program `8wayshow.py` that displays numbered table and displays all text strings reoriented left to right**
Parts 1 through 3 are shown in clear, with no spoilers so no need for hidden text.

**Part 4: Plain-strings from the letter table as output by `8wayshow.py`**
Part 4 is in hidden text (rollover-revealed text) although it does not identify any words, merely shows text strings from the eight  orientations reoriented for left-to-right reading.  It is the reference table for numbered word references in part 5.

**Part 5: Five triples (two new, three old) & some herrings** (in hidden text)
**Part 6: A bunch of words found** (in hidden text)
Part 6 also includes half-a-dozen things that look to me like they might be wordlike in some language I don't know.

---

---

**Part 1: Explanation of numbering system**

In following, I numbered rows and columns from 0 to 16. 
In word references below, letters a...h represent eight orientations: → a, ← b, ↓ c, ↑ d, ↗ e, ↙ f, ↖ g, ↘ h.

Diagonals are numbered such that if row or column numbering continues forward and back and around corners as shown below, each diagonal with six or more letters can be identified by a number from 6 to 28.  D6-D17 are of lengths 6...17.  Some numbers align with axes of diagonals, others with first characters, others only obscurely.

For example, 6a *aabotr* is a right-ascending (↗) diagonal in line with two 6's and 16b *leengpenvpaozzlb* is a left-descending (↙) diagonal in line with two 16's.  The right-descending (↘) diagonal 11h *aoahsalrkio* looks like it's in line with a top 5 and right 28; in a wrapped view, it also is in line with two 11's.  To be less obscure (but rather more bulky) the table could be printed with four sets of label lines on each side.

---

**Part 2: Numbering shown around the table of letters**

```
       33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
33  0   p  y  b  e  g  r  a  f  e  n  i  s  x  j  r  l  p   17 16
32  1   i  s  v  a  t  b  a  o  e  v  a  n  o  r  e  a  o   18 15
31  2   y  a  b  o  a  r  d  g  a  m  e  n  r  e  k  m  m   19 14
30  3   y  n  b  d  l  p  z  r  v  h  k  m  n  n  q  r  m   20 13
29  4   p  a  o  b  l  a  g  i  a  a  s  g  n  i  c  h  i   21 12
28  5   a  b  m  s  y  n  t  y  m  a  p  a  i  v  a  t  e   22 11
27  6   s  b  r  e  t  t  s  p  i  e  l  o  l  u  f  e  r   23 10
26  7   p  o  r  m  i  t  s  k  n  s  o  e  t  r  m  r  d   24  9
25  8   o  r  h  g  r  i  a  v  e  o  s  a  z  a  k  n  o   25  8
24  9   o  l  h  c  m  v  p  u  g  n  j  p  k  j  a  i  b   26  7
23 10   r  e  m  z  h  a  e  h  a  a  o  p  o  a  i  n  o   27  6
22 11   t  t  a  c  o  n  s  c  i  e  n  c  e  h  r  g  k   28  5
21 12   s  a  n  z  s  k  i  s  r  l  g  n  g  d  c  e  o   29  4
20 13   j  d  z  i  t  i  e  x  r  p  h  s  y  y  r  r  c   30  3
19 14   h  l  a  t  a  t  r  r  a  m  i  r  g  s  a  s  k   31  2
18 15   b  o  n  f  g  s  d  g  m  u  a  b  l  e  f  p  a   32  1
17 16   i  p  o  g  e  f  x  s  o  c  g  e  w  e  t  e  n   33  0
       17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
       16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

---

**Part 3: Python program `8wayshow.py` that displays numbered table and displays all text strings reoriented left to right**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Re http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5763/international-wordsearch
t = ['pybegrafenisxjrlp', 'isvatbaoevanoreao', 'yaboardgamenrekmm',
     'ynbdlpzrvhkmnnqrm', 'paoblagiaasgnichi', 'abmsyntymapaivate',
     'sbrettspielolufer', 'pormitsknsoetrmrd', 'orhgriaveosazakno',
     'olhcmvpugnjpkjaib', 'remzhaehaaopoaino', 'ttaconsciencehrgk',
     'sanzskisrlgngdceo', 'jdzitiexrphsyyrrc', 'hlatatrramirgsask',
     'bonfgsdgmuablefpa', 'ipogefxsocgeweten']
tr = [''.join(reversed(s)) for s in t]

# Create u by transposing t
n = len(t);    d = 2*n-1        # n = #rows,  d = #diags
u = [''.join(t[i][j] for i in range(n)) for j in range(n)]
ur = [''.join(reversed(s)) for s in u]

# Rotate t +/- 45 degrees, returning result r
def rotor(rdir):
    r = []
    for i in range(5,n):
        x = [' ']*n
        for j in range(i+1):
            x[j] = t[i-j][j] if rdir else t[i-j][n-1-j]
        r.append(''.join(x))

    for i in range(n-6):
        x = [' ']*n
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            x[j-i-1] = t[n+i-j][j] if rdir else t[n+i-j][n-1-j]
        r.append(''.join(x))
    return r

v = rotor(1);   vr = [''.join(reversed(s)) for s in v]
w = rotor(0);   wr = [''.join(reversed(s)) for s in w]

def printhead(first,last,step):
    print '      ',
    for i in range(first,last,step):
        print '{:2}'.format(i),
    print

printhead(d,n-1,-1)
printhead(0,n,1)
for i in range(n):
    print '{:2} {:2}  '.format(d-i, i),
    for j in range(n):
        print '{:2}'.format(t[i][j]),
    print ' {:2} {:2}'.format(i+n, n-i-1)
printhead(n,d+1,1)
printhead(n-1,-1,-1)
print

for i in range(n):
    print '{:2} {} {} {} {}'.format(i, t[i], tr[i], u[i], ur[i])

for i in range(len(v)):
    print '{:2} {} {} {} {}'.format(i+6, v[i], vr[i], w[i], wr[i])
```

---

**Part 4: Plain-strings from the letter table as output by `8wayshow.py`**
Part 4 is in hidden text (rollover-revealed text) although it does not identify any words, merely shows text strings from the eight  orientations reoriented for left-to-right reading.  It is the reference table for numbered word references in part 5.

> 0 pybegrafenisxjrlp plrjxsinefargebyp piyypaspoortsjhbi ibhjstroopsapyyip 
>   1 isvatbaoevanoreao oaeronaveoabtavsi ysanabborletadlop poldatelrobbanasy 
>   2 yaboardgamenrekmm mmkernemagdraobay bvbbomrrhhmanzano onaznamhhrrmobbvb 
>   3 ynbdlpzrvhkmnnqrm mrqnnmkhvrzpldbny eaodbsemgczczitfg gftizczcgmesbdoae 
>   4 paoblagiaasgnichi ihcingsaaigalboap gtallytirmhostage egatsohmrityllatg 
>   5 abmsyntymapaivate etaviapamytnysmba rbrpanttivankitsf fstiknavittnaprbr 
>   6 sbrettspielolufer refuloleipstterbs aadzgtssapesierdx xdreisepasstgzdaa 
>   7 pormitsknsoetrmrd drmrteosnkstimrop fogriypkvuhcsxrgs sgrxschuvkpyirgof 
>   8 orhgriaveosazakno onkazasoevairghro eeavaminegairramo omarriagenimavaee 
>   9 olhcmvpugnjpkjaib biajkpjngupvmchlo nvmhaaesonaelpmuc cumpleanoseaahmvn 
>  10 remzhaehaaopoaino oniaopoaaheahzmer iaeksplosjonghiag gaihgnojsolpskeai 
>  11 ttaconsciencehrgk kgrhecneicsnocatt snnmgaoeappcnsrbe ebrsncppaeoagmnns 
>  12 sanzskisrlgngdceo oecdgnglrsiksznas xornniltzkoegyglw wlgygeokztlinnrox 
>  13 jdzitiexrphsyyrrc crryyshprxeitizdj jrenivurajahdysee eesydhajaruvinerj 
>  14 hlatatrramirgsask ksasgrimarrtatalh rekqcafmkaircraft tfarcriakmfacqker 
>  15 bonfgsdgmuablefpa apfelbaumgdsgfnob lamrhterningerspe epsregninrethrmal 
>  16 ipogefxsocgeweten netewegcosxfegopi pommierdobokockan nakcokobodreimmop 
>   
>   6 aabotr                       rtobaa ehqeos                       soeqhe 
>   7 sbodaba                     abadobs rtcnrni                     inrnctr 
>   8 pbmblraf                   farlbmbp deainnan                   nanniaed 
>   9 oorslpdoe                 eodplsroo orfvnmeve                 evemnvfro 
>  10 orreyazgen               negzayerro bnmuigkmef               femkgiumnb 
>  11 rlhmtngravi             ivargntmhlr oikrlashaoa             aoahsalrkio 
>  12 tehgittivmas           samvittighet knaatopavgar           ragvapotaank 
>  13 stmcrtsyahenx         xnehaystrcmts ogijzelaardbg         gbdraalezjigo 
>  14 jaazmispmaknoj       jonkampsimzaaj cerakaoemizrte       etrzimeoakarec 
>  15 hdnchvakiasmrrr     rrrmsaikavhcndh krchopssiygpaab     baapgyisspohcrk 
>  16 blzzoapvnepgneel   leengpenvpaozzlb asrdepjonptalovy   yvolatpnojpedrsa 
>  17 ioaisneueslannkap paknnalseuensiaoi npaygconeksnldbsp psbdlnskenocgyapn 
>  18 pnttkshgoooiiqmo   omqiioooghskttnp efsynnagvstybbai   iabbytsvgannysfe 
>  19 ofaiicanselvcrm     mrcvlesnaciiafo tegsgeauattsony     ynosttauaegsget 
>  20 ggtesiajatuahm       mhautajaisetgg elrhlihpiiemay       yameiiphilhrle 
>  21 esrxreopzrfti         itfrzpoerxrse wbiprcevrmrbp         pbrmrvecrpibw 
>  22 fdrrlnpkamee           eemakpnlrrdf eamrssamgrba           abrgmassrmae 
>  23 xgapgcojkrr             rrkjocgpagx guaxinhchos             sohchnixaug 
>  24 smmhneaand               dnaaenhmms cmrekozhrp               prhzokermc 
>  25 ouisghiio                 oiihgsiuo ogriscmlo                 olmcsirgo 
>  26 carydrnb                   bnrdyrac sdttzaeo                   oeazttds 
>  27 gbgycgo                     ogcygbg xsaintr                     rtniasx 
>  28 elsrek                       kersle fgtzat                       taztgf

---

**Part 5: Five triples & some herrings** (in hidden text)

Two new triples:

> 04c hostage  (English)  5c,13g 
>  05c panttivanki  (Finnish)   hostage 4c,13g 
>  13g gijzelaar (Dutch),  hostage 4c,5c 
>  
>  01d robbanás     (Hungarian), explosion  10c 
>  10c eksplosjon   (Norwegian Bokmål),     an explosion  1d 
>  13c rajahdys   (Finnish), explosion 10c,1d

Three old triples (With credits to @w0lf; although I'd found the rest on my own, I'd missed a Czech word and a Norwegian word):

> 01b aeronave   (Italian) dirigible; (Spanish/Portuguese) aircraft
>  01c letadlo      (Czech)  aircraft  14c,1b 
>  14c aircraft (English)  1b,1c 
>  11a conscience (English)  16a,12f 
>  12f samvittighet  (Norwegian Bokmaal) conscience 11a,16a 
>  16a geweten  (Dutch)  conscience  11a,12f 
>  02c manzano     (Spanish)     apple tree  15b 
>  15b apfelbaum  (German)  apple tree  2c,16c 
>  16c pommier  (French)  apple tree 2c,15b

Herrings:

> 00a begrafenis   (Dutch), burial, funeral  20f 
>  20f hautajaiset  (Finnish)   funeral, memorial service; wake 0a 
>  00c paspoort     (Dutch), passport etc    6d 
>  06d reisepass (German)    passport   0c 
>  07a pormit ?  (eg for 0c, 6d) 
>  01a svatba       (Czech), wedding  8d 
>  08d marriage  (English)  1a 
>  05a syntymapaivat   (Finnish), birthday  9d 
>  09d cumpleanos (Asturian) & (Spanish)  birthday  5a 
>  02a boardgame  (English)  6a 
>  06a brettspiel  (German)  board game   2a 
>  15c terning  (Norwegian Bokmål/Nynorsk)  a die or dice  16c 
>  16c dobokocka  (Hungarian),  (games) dice 15c

---

**Part 6: A bunch of words found** (in hidden text)

> 00a begrafenis   Dutch, burial, funeral  20f 
>  00c paspoort     Dutch, passport etc    6d 
>  00c spoort       Dutch, ?, in spoort na/op/aan 
>  00d stroop       Dutch, syrup 
>  01a svatba       Czech, wedding  8d 
>  01b aeronave   Italian dirigible; Spanish/Portuguese aircraft  14c,1c ## 
>  01c letadlo      Czech  aircraft  ## 14c,1b 
>  01d robbanás     Hungarian, explosion  10c 
>  02a boardgame   6a 
>  02c manzano     Spanish     apple tree  15b 
>  04c hostage   5c,13g ## 
>  04e yazgen ? like Spanish yazgan 
>  05a syntyma  Finnish birth  
>  05a paivat   Finnish an inexact time; eg syntyma paivat = ~birthday ? 9d 
>  05c panttivanki  Finnish   hostage 4c,13g ## 
>  06a brettspiel  German  board game   2a 
>  06c pesier  ? like Italian pesiera, pesiere set of weights 
>  06d reisepass German    passport   0c 
>  07a pormit ?  (eg for 0c, 6d) 
>  08a riaveo ? 
>  08d marriage   1a 
>  08d agenim ? 
>  09d cumpleanos Asturian & Spanish  birthday  5a 
>  10a haehaa ? like Danish haehae, haha 
>  10c eksplosjon   Norwegian Bokmål,     an explosion  1d 
>  11a conscience  16a,12f ## 
>  11f vittighet ? like Danish  joke, witticism, pun 
>  12a sanzskisr ? 
>  12c niltzkoegy ? 
>  12f samvittighet  Norwegian, Bokmaal 11a,16a ## conscience 
>  13d ruvine  Friulian,  ruin 
>  13g gijzelaar Dutch,  hostage 4c, 5c ## 
>  14c aircraft  1b,1c 
>  15a muable  French   mutable 
>  15b apfelbaum  German  apple tree  2c,16c ## 
>  15c terning  Norwegian Bokmål/Nynorsk  a die or dice  16c 
>  15d regnin Catalan ~ to reign, to rule 
>  16a ipoge ? like Italian cavern? 
>  16a geweten  Dutch  conscience  11a,12f ## 
>  16b netewe       Kurdish, nation 
>  16c pommier  French  apple tree 2c,15b ## 
>  16c dobokocka  Hungarian,  (games) dice 15c 
>  16f leengpen, Myanmar 
>  17 
>  18h Gannys = name of a Roman general  
>  19 
>  20f hautajaiset  Finnish   funeral, memorial service; wake 0a

---

Comment: +1 for an answer that is much longer than the question :c) And also for the very systematic approach. Still waiting for the "finals" though, okay?

Comment: For languages, it looks like Czech Dutch Finnish French German Hungarian Italian Norwegian Spanish have words that are integral parts of pairs or triples. Portuguese *aeronave* is one word of a triple and
Asturian *cumpleanos* is one word of a pair but those words are in other languages also, so they are less integral.

Comment: +1 for summarizing the languages. The **nine intentionally** used languages are **English, Spanish, Norwegian, Hungarian, Finnish, German, French, Dutch, Czech**. But as noted in the puzzle, similarity of languages open up more possibilities.

Comment: BmyGuest, I was unable to locate a sixth triple, but saw a few more words or word parts not yet listed in my answer (eg troops; eg ogrisc part of Croation ogrisci).  I updated my code so may update it in a few days.

Answer (score 8):

So far, I managed to find these triplets:

1.

> **MANZANO** (Spanish) - column 3
>  
>  **POMMIER** (French) - column 17
>  
>  **APFELBAUM** (German) - line 16

2.

> **GEWETEN** (Dutch) - line 17
>  
>  **CONSCIENCE** (English) - line 12
>  
>  **SAMVITTIGHET** (Norwegian, Bokmaal) - line 1, col 12, diagonal towards SW

3.

> **AERONAVE** (French) - line 2
>  
>  
>  **AIRCRAFT** (English) - column 15
>  
>  
>  **LETADLO** (Czech) - column 2

Potential candidates/red herrings:

> **REISEPASS** (German)
>  
>  
>  **PASPOORT** (Dutch)
>  
>  
>  
>  **BOARDGAME** (English)
>  
>  
>  **BRETTSPIEL** (German)
>  
>  
>  
>  **HOSTAGE** (English)
>  
>  
>  **GIJZELAAR** (Dutch)

Comment: Nice. All valid and good progress. (Plus you've identified 5 of 9 languages.) +1 for being the first to post some results in a cooperative spirit.

Comment: ..and now its 7/9 languages. You're getting closer!

Comment: @BmyGuest I've had lots of fun working on this. I wish I had more time to find the others. Thank you for this great puzzle! ;)